# Uncaught typeError: cannot read property 'markers' off null

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having trouble to load a google map with more than 108 markers. 
When I filter values up to 59 markers, the map loads perfectly, but when I don't want to filter de map and want to show all the markers, it does not load at all and have this message by google chrome console: Uncaught typeError: cannot read property 'markers' off null.

This is part of the code where the problem appears:

```
var gmap = {
    addMarkers: function(jsonData) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i=0; i<jsonData.markers.length; i++) {
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(jsonData.markers[i].latitud, jsonData.markers[i].longitud);
            bounds.extend(point);
            gmap.createMarker(point, jsonData.markers[i].icontype, jsonData.markers[i].label, jsonData.markers[i].html);
        }
        gmap.el.fitBounds(bounds);
    },
  center: function(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, len = gmap.markers.length; i < len; i++) {
        bounds.extend(gmap.markers[i].getPosition());
    }
    gmap.el.fitBounds(bounds);
    return gmap;
},


createMarker: function (point,icontype,title,html) {
        if (typeof icontype == 'undefined'){
            icontype = 'a';
        }

        if (typeof html != 'undefined'){
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                if (typeof gmap.iw != 'undefined'){
                    gmap.iw.close();
                }
                marker.setIcon(marker.getIcon().replace(/pin-([a-c])/,'pin-b'));
                gmap.iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<div class="infowindow">'+html+'</div>'
                }); 
                gmap.iw.open(gmap.el,marker);
            });
        }
        gmap.markers.push(marker);
        return gmap;
    },
    load: function(idx, elem){
        var zoom = 11, options = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false
        }, createMarker;
        gmap.dom = $(elem);
        if ($('#js_id_rubro').length){
            options.zoom = 11;
            options.mapTypeControl = true;
            options.mapTypeControlOptions = {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            }
            $.getJSON('/ajax.php','do=get_mapas_rubro&id_rubro='+$('#js_id_rubro').text()+'&filtros='+$('#js_filtros').text(),gmap.addMarkers);
        }else{
            createMarker = 1;
            options.center = new google.maps.LatLng(gmap.dom.data('latitude'),gmap.dom.data('longitude'));
            options.zoom = 14;
            options.mapTypeControl = false;
```

Can it be because the variable 'markers' is not defined?  or  just thinking another solution: Ive seen a lot of maps that groups markers and when zoomed, shows all individual markers. I dont want to to this, but i think that it will be solution , what do you think? please, help!

Comment: `jsonData` doesn't exist for some reason. Check how it's being passed in to that method.

Comment: perhaps the data for one of the markers (after 59) is bad (making your JSON not valid or the request for it fail).  You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Please update your question with requested code, it is almost impossible to read in the comments.

Comment: yo make me realized that the jsonData  is not working for more than 59 markers because when i run the ajax.php manually  don't  show anything